# adding new row with jquery to asp.net grid view and need to access the row from c#

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I need to add new row which contains 4 tds and 4 text boxes in it

and i need to make use like gridview.rows[i];

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do ?

Answer (score -1):

The following link best describes what you require:
http://technico.qnownow.com/how-to-insert-update-delete-rows-in-asp-net-gridview-control/